# AutoLayout: multiline label and fixed-size button

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uilabel, snapkit

I'm trying to replicate the following layout from the Kayak app:
[image: kayak app]

The layout consists of *UICollectionViewCell* with a *UILabel* and a *INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton*.

However, in my implementation the label doesn't force the cell to stretch further when the text doesn't fit:
[image: Clipping text]

**How could I make the *UICollectionViewCell* grow with the label, and not truncate the label to the size of the cell?**

The whole code for the cell:

```
final class AddToSiriCell: CornerMaskCellBase {
  lazy var button: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton = {
    let b = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .whiteOutline)
    return b
  }()

  lazy var textLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
  }()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configureViews()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  private func configureViews() {
    textLabel.text = "View balance with your pre-recorded Siri Command .View balance with your pre-recorded Siri Command  View balance with your pre-recorded Siri Command View balance with your pre-recorded Siri Command "
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    [button, textLabel].forEach(contentView.addSubview)
    button.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.top.bottom.trailing.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
    }

    textLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.top.bottom.leading.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide).priority(.required)
      make.trailing.equalTo(button.snp.leading).priority(.required)
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1: Added "Base Class" with fixed width**
Here is the base class I use for all the cells in the UICollectionView:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class AutoSizingCellBase: UICollectionViewCell {
  override class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool {
    return true
  }

  private final var widthConstraint: Constraint?

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(padding: 14)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func updateConstraints() {
    if widthConstraint == nil {
      if let window = window {
        let width = window.bounds.width - 16
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
          widthConstraint = make.width.equalTo(width).priority(.required).constraint
        }
      }
      contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    }
    super.updateConstraints()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your top constraint on both the label and the button to `greaterThanOrEqual`

Set your bottom constraint on both the label and the button to `lessThanOrEqual`

---

**Edit:**

Both should also have `centerY` constraints.

Here is a complete example (I'm not on iOS 12, so I used a standard `UIButton` in place of `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton`). I also set the background of the label to cyan to make it easy to see its resulting frame:

```
//
//  SnapTableViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/19/18.
//

import UIKit

class SnapCell: UITableViewCell {

    lazy var theButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.backgroundColor = .yellow
        b.setTitle("Add to Siri", for: .normal)
        b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        b.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        b.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        b.layer.borderWidth = 1
        return b
    }()

    lazy var theLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return label
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configureViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configureViews()
    }

    func configureViews() -> Void {

        contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        [theButton, theLabel].forEach(contentView.addSubview)

        // constrain button size to 120 x 40
        theButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(120)
            make.height.equalTo(40)
        }

        // constrain button to trailing margin
        theButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.trailing.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
        }

        // constrain button top to greaterThanOrEqualTo margin
        theButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
        }

        // constrain button bottom to lessThanOrEqualTo margin
        theButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
        }

        // also constrain button to centerY
        theButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerY.equalTo(contentView.snp.centerY)
        }

        // constrain label to leading margin
        theLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.leading.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
        }

        // constrain label top to greaterThanOrEqualTo margin
        theLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
        }

        // constrain label bottom to lessThanOrEqualTo margin
        theLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
        }

        // also constrain label to centerY
        theLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerY.equalTo(contentView.snp.centerY)
        }

        // constrain label trailing to 8-pts from button leading
        theLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.trailing.equalTo(theButton.snp.leading).offset(-8)
        }

    }

}

class SnapTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SnapCell", for: indexPath) as! SnapCell

        switch indexPath.row % 4 {

        case 0:
            cell.theLabel.text = "One line label."

        case 1:
            cell.theLabel.text = "This label has\nTwo Lines."

        case 2:
            cell.theLabel.text = "This label has enough text that is will wrap to Three Lines (on an iPhone 7)."

        default:
            cell.theLabel.text = "View balance with your pre-recorded Siri Command .View balance with your pre-recorded Siri Command  View balance with your pre-recorded Siri Command View balance with your pre-recorded Siri Command "

        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code example and the screenshot

Comment: @RichardTopchiy - see my edited answer for a complete example.

Comment: The demo project you've presented looks great! That's exactly the behavior I want. However, I use UICollectionView, I'll take a look how it behaves too...

Comment: Your example works well, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, the problem seems be in the way sizing is handled in my app.

Comment: Interesting, I ran your example and then re-created the same cell with the UICollectionView and got completely different result (with self-sizing cells on): https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8013017/47292030-7a078700-d60e-11e8-9b55-03a231eb750d.png

Comment: It looks like your cells are missing Width constraints / sizing. You'll need to post the rest of your code that is setting the item sizes.

Comment: absolutely, I just wonder, how could I set the requirement of making the cells of the width of the `UICollectionView`. Playing with `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of the label helped to resolve the issue, but essentially, I have to "guess" the right width.

Comment: I've added the base class which I use for all of the cells with fixed width.

Comment: There are many, many discussions about how to do "auto-sizing" collection view cells. Lots of them work only "sort-of." Personally, if I was doing a "single column" collection view (which it looks like you're doing)... unless you're using some other collection view features which are *not* available with table views, I would use a table view instead. Seems to be much, much easier to get the layout you're after.

Comment: I absolutely agree, however, it's not possible to use TableView in this case. The layout in question has a card-like interface, which is only possible with the `UICollectionView`.

Also, I don't use AutoSizing in Apple's way, I use the "sizing cell" approach, where I create a special cell used only for sizing for every cell class and cache the results.

Comment: hmmm... "card-like interface"? How is that only possible with collection view?

Comment: The cards could be of infinite size (i.e. should be scrollable) and there should be shadow covering the whole card. I wasn't able to achieve this effect by using just UITableView as I wasn't able to make the shadow look "unified". There was some spacing between the cells which made the shadow look weird.

Comment: Apparently, it's the fact that I use `UICollectionView` that makes the whole issue. The very same implementation works perfectly in UITableView.

Comment: Well, we're pretty far beyond the scope of this question. Based on the images you included in your original question, though, I don't see anything that cannot be done with a table view.

Comment: Yes, but that helps to frame the question in a way that I HAVE to do it with UICollectionView. Of course, I'd use UITableView if I could, but this software has multiple requirements and design-wise requirements too ;)

Comment: the issue was related to incorrect width constraint configuration on my side.

Comment: Using your approach, i.e. `greaterThanOrEqualTo ` constraints, I was able to achieve the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Set the label's top, bottom and left constraints with superview i.e cell's content view. Now give your button to fixed height and width constraints and provide top, left and right margins, left margin should be with your label. Now set your label's number of lines property as zero. Any doubt please comment.